# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

i have a code two filter a table by using color and value (refered to stackoverflow) , but am getting an error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null .**

It shows me this error .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"OutputNew.csv",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data){
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML()">PDF</button><input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" placeholder="color"><br><input type="text" id="myInputtext" name="myInput" placeholder="First Name"><br><div id="VMTable"><table id="myTable" class="table table-striped"">';
    // var table_data = '<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" placeholder="color"><br><input type="text" id="myInputtext" name="myInput" placeholder="First Name"><br><table id="myTable" class="table table-striped"">';
    for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++) {
     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(',');
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++){
      if(count === 0){
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }else{
          if(cell_data[cell_count] .includes("Not Matching")){
                var ret = cell_data[cell_count].replace('Not Matching','');
                if (ret == ""){
                  table_data += '<td>'+ret+'</td>'
                }else{
                  table_data += '<td data-color="red"><span class="badge-danger">'+ret+'</span></td>'
                }
          }else if(cell_data[cell_count] .includes("Matching")){
                var ret = cell_data[cell_count].replace('Matching','');
                if (ret == ""){
                  table_data += '<td>'+ret+'</td>'
                }else{
                  table_data += '<td data-color="green"><span class="badge-complete">'+ret+'</span></td>';
                }
          }else{
              table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
          }
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    
    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
   }
  });   
 }); 
});
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInputtext");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        if (tr[i].style.display !== "none") {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        }
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
  
if (filter==="") {
document.getElementById("myInput").value="";
document.getElementById("myInputtext").value="";
[...document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr")].forEach(el => { el.style.display = "" });
}
}





function filterTable(event) {
  var filter = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
  var rows = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody").rows;

  if (filter === "RED" || filter === "R" || filter === "RE") {
    filter = "badge-danger";
  } else if (filter === "GREEN" || filter === "G" || filter === "GR" || filter === "GRE" || filter === "GREE") {
    filter = "badge-complete";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var Col1 = rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
    var Col2 = rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var Col3 = rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
    if (Col1.indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
      Col2.indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
      Col3.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      if (rows[i].style.display !== "none") {
        rows[i].style.display = "";
      }
    } else {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
if (filter==="") {
document.getElementById("myInput").value="";
document.getElementById("myInputtext").value="";
[...document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr")].forEach(el => { el.style.display = "" });
}    
}

document.querySelector('#myInputtext').addEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false);
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filterTable, false);

        function demoFromHTML() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
            source = $('#VMTable')[0];
            specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
                    return true
                }
            };
            margins = {
                top: 80,
                bottom: 60,
                left: 40,
                width: 522
            };
            // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
            // 'inches' in this case
            pdf.fromHTML(
                    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                    margins.left, // x coord
                    margins.top, {// y coord
                        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    },
            function(dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }
            , margins);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
div#loadbutton {
  margin-left: 158px;
}

h1#Heading {
  margin-left: 154px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.table-responsive {
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  WIDTH: 223%;
  MARGIN-LEFT: -205PX;
}

.badge-Nill {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 49px;
  padding: 9px 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 127px;
}

.badge-danger {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 49px;
  padding: 9px 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 127px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  width: 152px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 310px;
}

table td {
  border: solid 1px #fab;
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.badge-complete {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 49px;
  padding: 9px 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: limegreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 127px;
}
h1#Heading {
    margin-left: 154px;
    margin-top: -44px;
}
div#employee_table {
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

 </style>
  <link rel = "icon" href = "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/gfg_200X200.png" type = "image/x-icon"> 
  <title>TValidator</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.debug.js"></script>

  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <!-- <img src="banner.png" id="banner"> -->
    <h1 id ="Heading">Validator</h1>
    <br />
    <div id ="loadbutton">
     <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
     
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here is output.csv

```
Application,FileName,ADG,KLHJ,POWB
ads,FileName1,jhjkhkjhMatching,jhjkhkNot Matching,jhjkhkjhMatching
adr,FileName2,databaseMatching,databaseMatching,databaseMatching
popo,FileName3,POEBMatching,POEBMatching,POEBMatching
```

so here it tells me to add even listener and i don't know where to add event listener in this code . since table is created dynamically based on csv and after button click table is loaded and then filter (require event listener) is done to table .

So please help me with adding event listener

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event listeners once the page loads. It is unable to find the element with id "myInputtext" when it is trying to attach the event listener.

As the addition of the event listeners is done outside any function, when the script is imported, it tries to add the event listeners and as it can't find, it throws an error.

Comment: Can you explain me where to add event listener and how to add

Comment: `window.onload = function(){
    //code for adding the event listener
}
`

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` means you're trying to add an event listener to an element that doesn't exist. If the element you're listening to is baked into the HTML code (meaning it exists when the page loads), make sure your event listener is waiting for the DOM content to load first:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // My Code
});
```

If the element you're listening for is created dynamiacally with Javascript, add the listener after the element is created. (First create the element and append it to the DOM, then add a listener for the element)

Lastly, you may have removed the element, so put a check in place that the element exists before you listen for an event.

If you're still having trouble, maybe get a fiddle going so we can try out your code.

Comment: So here the table or the element is loaded after a button click ., so can explain me where to add that

Comment: You'll want to find the code that loads the element, and add an event listener right after that element is created. So if you have a function called `makeTable()`, be sure to include in that function the event listeners for that table element. When you try to create an event listener, it looks for the element and then tries to add the event listener. If the element doesnt exist yet, it's going to throw an error, so be sure you're making the event listener after the element exists on the page.

Comment: I just updated the code , so the thing is my table is loaded by a button , and event listener is actually used in filtering table . (Given in question) , so are you saying i have to add it in table during creation or during filter

Comment: yeah i just created a fiddle , can you please help me now , i don't know where to add that